# how to midify server.xml on openshift tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, openshift, server.xml

I want to modify server.xml on openshfit Tomcat 6. But it alway is not successful.
I have tried modify below file.

```
./app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/config/server.xml
./jbossews/template/.openshift/config/server.xml
./jbossews/conf/server.xml
```

Once I commit a code, server will be built and deployed. Then the server.xml will be recovered a default version.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could explain in your question what you are actually trying to accomplish, then how you are doing it and ask if there is another way to do it that works?

Comment: Thanks, I want to use https for two-way mode.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the [docs](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-getting-started.html):

> server.xml can be found in the {git repo}/.openshift/config/
>   directory. Please be careful when making a change to the file. Also,
>   make sure the Tomcat server restarts after making the change.

Just tried it successfully.